# Python - pandas different size of cartesian product every run

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, cartesian-product

I have two dataframes in python, and I want to do a cartesian product of them. 
For that I have used the merge with the same key command as follow:

```
print("dna", df_genes.size)
print("names",df_citations.size)
df_genes['key'] = 0
df_citations['key'] = 0
df = pd.merge(df_genes, df_citations, on='key').drop('key', axis = 1)

print("df before",df.size)
```

However, every run I get a different size for the cartesian product - and it is never the multiplication of the first two dataframes.
For example, in the last run I got:

```
('dna', 7437309)
('names', 165)
('df before', 490862394)
```

(As you can see, the difference is quite big)

This sounds odd to me. Does anyone have a clue?

Comment: Please share your 2 dataframes so we can reproduce your code

Comment: One of them is really big. You sure you want it?

Comment: @CmpScienceLearner not the full dataframes. Give a try yourself first with 5 rows of `df_genes` and 3 rows of `df_citations`. If your code gives the same kind of unexpected output, then share these few rows like this people who try to answer can reproduce your problem and find a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use .size, which shows the number of rows times columns. To check if your cartesian product worked, you expect that when df1 has 5 rows and df2 has 3 rows, the cartesian product would result in 15 rows. This you can check by replacing .size by .shape or .shape[0]

In your case:

```
print("dna", df_genes.shape[0])
print("names", df_citations.shape[0])
df_genes['key'] = 0
df_citations['key'] = 0
df = pd.merge(df_genes, df_citations, on='key').drop('key', axis = 1)

print("df before", df.shape[0])
```